# Complicated SELECT statement in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

Can you please help me with one complicated select statement?

I have a table like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| ID | User_name | Situation |    Date_time    |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
|  1 | Alex      |         1 |   14.3.18 11:30 |
|  4 | Alex      |         2 |   14.3.18 11:35 |
|  6 | Alex      |         3 |   14.3.18 12:30 |
|  7 | Johnny    |         1 |   15.3.18 10:01 |
|  9 | Johnny    |         2 |   15.3.18 10:05 |
| 12 | Johnny    |         3 |   15.3.18 10:20 |
| 14 | Alex      |         1 |   20.3.18 20:00 |
| 15 | Alex      |         2 |   20.3.18 20:25 |
| 17 | Alex      |         3 |   20.3.18 21:25 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
```

And I need a select statement, which will give me the following result:
User_name,  Date_time_1 (Date_time of situation 1), Date_time_3 (Date_time of situation 3).

*In this case the result will have just 3 rows (2 for Alex and 1 for Johnny). Each row will contain 3 columns as described above.

And sorry for the formatting - I posted that from a mobile. I will add the result table when I will get to PC.*

That's how the output should looks like:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| ID | User_name |Date_time_1  |   Date_time_3   |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Alex      |14.3.18 11:30|   14.3.18 12:30 |
|  2 | Johnny    |15.3.18 10:01|   15.3.18 10:20 |
|  3 | Alex      |20.3.18 20:00|   20.3.18 21:25 |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your table and also show us what the expected output looks like.  And include any query you have already tried.

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen said, add a table of desired output to the post. What about Alex, for instance. Should he/she appeare once or twice?

Comment: @Ulquiorra: Can you update the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT User_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Situation = 1 THEN Date_time END) AS date_time_1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Situation = 3 THEN Date_time END) AS date_time_3
FROM tab
GROUP BY User_name;
```

## EDIT

> *In this case the result will have just 3 rows (2 for Alex and 1 for Johnny)*

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT t.*, SUM(CASE WHEN Situation=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          OVER(PARTITION BY User_name ORDER BY id) AS s
   FROM tab t
)
SELECT User_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Situation = 1 THEN Date_time END) AS date_time_1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Situation = 3 THEN Date_time END) AS date_time_3
FROM cte
GROUP BY s, User_name;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd24f60b780ef8b2d1d7789bf30010cf)**

Comment: Why do you need aggregation?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Because as I understand requirements, OP wants date1 and date3 in single row per User_name.

Comment: Thank You a lot, that works. I just needed to add WHERE to the first SELECT - otherwise, there were some weird rows in results (in real table with more data). So it works with this: 

FROM tab t WHERE Situation = 1 OR
                                  Situation = 3